# Create mdb file to debug managed DLL in Unity

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, batch-file, scripting

I'm trying to debug my managed DLL within Unity. It used to work fine on Unity 2018.x

Now I have Unity 2019.3 and I can't debug anymore (my DLLs are working fine I just can't debug them).

My DLL and its pdb file are in the Assets folder. That used to be enough to be able to debug them.

Reading this documentation : https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UsingDLL.html, I'm trying to create the mdb file.

First issue, the documentation says I have to pass the .pdb file as a parameter while most links on google say to pass the .dll

This link also states that I should change the working directory of my .bat file to be able to use pdb2mdb.exe : https://answers.unity.com/questions/294195/pdb2mdb-usage-error-from-command-line.html

Here is my code:

```
set PathToLib="Libraries\"
if exist Libraries\LibBDD.dll  (
    echo Before switching directory for my lib %CD%
    cd %PathToLib% 
    echo new directory %CD%
    @pause
    "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0\pdb2mdb.exe" LibBDD.dll

    @pause
    cd ..\..\..\..\..\
    echo LibBDD done, new directory %CD%
    )
```

First of all I'm not sure if my CD command is working since the path remains the same. But I don't get any exception.

With this code I get:

> Fatal error: Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.PdbDebugException: Unknown custom
>   metadata item kind: 6    à
>   Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.PdbFunction.ReadCustomMetadata(BitAccess bits)    à
>   Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.PdbFunction..ctor(String module, ManProcSym proc,
>   BitAccess bits)    à
>   Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.PdbFunction.LoadManagedFunctions(String module,
>   BitAccess bits, UInt32 limit, Boolean readStrings)    à
>   Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.PdbFile.LoadFuncsFromDbiModule(BitAccess bits,
>   DbiModuleInfo info, IntHashTable names, ArrayList funcList, Boolean
>   readStrings, MsfDirectory dir, Dictionary`2 nameIndex, PdbReader
>   reader)    à Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.PdbFile.LoadFunctions(Stream read,
>   BitAccess bits, Boolean readAllStrings)    à
>   Pdb2Mdb.Driver.Convert(AssemblyDefinition assembly, Stream pdb,
>   MonoSymbolWriter mdb)

Without the CD I get:

> Mono pdb to mdb debug symbol store converter Usage: pdb2mdb assembly

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 Community.

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong and why I can't debug anymore in Unity. I've tried to add the csproj to the solution in VS but it doesn't do the trick anymore, the symbols are not loaded.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variables are not behaving as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like something changed in 2019.3 and for some reason Unity no longer generates the mdb files automatically.

The solution is to set your pdb's to **portable** instead of **full** which the the default you can do this by following the instructions from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-set-debug-and-release-configurations?view=vs-2019#generate-symbol-files-for-a-c-aspnet-or-visual-basic-project). After this you no longer have any need for the mdb files.

Step by step instructions from the link above:

> 1. In Solution Explorer, select the project.
> 2. Select the **Properties** icon (or press **Alt+Enter**).
> 3. In the side pane, choose **Build** (or **Compile** in Visual Basic).
> 4. In the **Configuration** list, choose **Debug** or **Release**.
> 5. Select the **Advanced** button (or the **Advanced Compile Options** button in Visual Basic).
> 6. In the **Debugging information** list (or the **Generate debug info** list in Visual Basic), choose **Portable**.
> 7. Build your project.

The compiler creates the symbol file(s) in the same folder as the executable or the main output file.

You can also read about it [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/automated-mdb-generation.755237/) and [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/running-pdb2mdb-with-unity-5-and-later.390456/)

Comment: Also, note that it looks like simple "step into" does not work - I need to open the file with the function I am stepping into and place a breakpoint there.

So if I place a breakpoint on this line:
q.Enqueue();

I need to open the file with the Queue class from the library sources in the same VS instance and place a breakpoint there. Then even the regular step into works. This is rather complicated since I need to manually find that class in the sources, but makes sense, since the sources are in totally unrelated projects. 

Just to be sure though, is this expected behavior?)

Comment: Yes! This totally worked for me, thanks! Stepping into with F11 works fine too.

Comment: Thank you so much ! This fixed a long due that we had with VS 2022 and Unity 2021